# No tengo la propiedad Sorted en un elemento ListBox

Tags: asp.net

Como dice la pregunta estoy trabajando en **ASP.NET**. Tengo un `listbox` y al entrar en las propiedades no me sale ***Sorted***. Tengo visual 2017, ¿a alguien le pasó algo similar?
Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Que deseas hacer en realidad

Answer (score 0):

Sorted es propia de ListBox de `Windows.forms`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Debes incluir System.Windows.Forms

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

**WinForms Sorted**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted(v=vs.110).aspx

En cambio si haces uso del ListBox de System.Web.UI, no podras acceder a ella.

**System.Web.UI ListBox:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hola!, ya lo importe pero sigue sin salir esa property.

Comment: Como mencione, si el listbox es del tipo Web.Ui, no te aparecera, en tal caso deberas generar un metodo personalizado para tal fin o implementar IComparer

Answer (score 0):

Si a alguien le sirve, pude ordenar el listbox con este codigo finalmente:

```
System.Collections.SortedList sorted = new SortedList();

foreach (ListItem ll in ListBox1.Items)
{
    sorted.Add(ll.Text, ll.Value);
}

ListBox1.Items.Clear();

foreach (String key in sorted.Keys)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(key, sorted[key].ToString()));
}
```